# How to average columns in a data frame based on grouping of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two CSV data that looks like this:

```
gene,stem1,stem2,stem3,b1,b2,b3,t1
foo,20,10,11,23,22,79,3
bar,17,13,505,12,13,88,1
qui,17,13,5,12,13,88,3
```

And this:

```
celltype,phenotype
SC,stem1
BC,b2
SC,stem2
SC,stem3
BC,b1
TC,t1
BC,b3
```

The data frame look like this:

```
In [5]: import pandas as pd
In [7]: main_df = pd.read_table("http://dpaste.com/2MRRRM3.txt", sep=",")

In [8]: main_df
Out[8]:
      gene  stem1  stem2  stem3  b1  b2  b3  t1
    0  foo     20     10     11  23  22  79   3
    1  bar     17     13    505  12  13  88   1
    2  qui     17     13      5  12  13  88   3


In [11]: source_df = pd.read_table("http://dpaste.com/091PNE5.txt", sep=",")

In [12]: source_df
Out[12]:
  celltype phenotype
0       SC     stem1
1       BC        b2
2       SC     stem2
3       SC     stem3
4       BC        b1
5       TC        t1
6       BC        b3
```

What I want to do is to average every column in `main_df` based on grouping
in `source_df`. So that it looks like this in the end:

```
       SC                BC                TC
foo   (20+10+11)/3     (23+22+79)/3        3/1
bar   (17+13+505)/3    (12+13+88)/3        1/1
qui   (17+13+5)/3      (12+13+88)/3        3/1
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert `source_df` to a `dict` and apply this to `main_df` using `.groupby()` on `axis=1`:

```
main_df.set_index('gene', inplace=True)
col_dict = source_df.set_index('phenotype').squeeze().to_dict()
main_df.groupby(col_dict, axis=1).mean()

             BC          SC  TC
gene                           
foo   41.333333   13.666667   3
bar   37.666667  178.333333   1
qui   37.666667   11.666667   3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set indices for `source_df` and for `main_df` then use [`pd.concat`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjR9rXPnLrKAhWEDiwKHWMLBq4QFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.concat.html&usg=AFQjCNF3rj64dj5jpwkx3HcltqlnAnBc4A&bvm=bv.112064104,d.bGQ) and [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by  `celltype`:

```
main_df.set_index('gene', inplace=True)
source_df.set_index("phenotype", inplace=True)

In [30]: pd.concat([main_df.T, source_df], axis=1)
Out[30]:
gene   foo  bar  qui celltype
b1      23   12   12       BC
b2      22   13   13       BC
b3      79   88   88       BC
stem1   20   17   17       SC
stem2   10   13   13       SC
stem3   11  505    5       SC
t1       3    1    3       TC


In [33]: pd.concat([main_df.T, source_df], axis=1).groupby(['celltype']).mean().T
Out[33]:
celltype         BC          SC  TC
gene
foo       41.333333   13.666667   3
bar       37.666667  178.333333   1
qui       37.666667   11.666667   3
```